# Laravel redirect returns page html instead redirecting

Tags: php, laravel

After Ajax sends data to the database I want to redirect the user to another page / view.
The data is added successfully to the database but redirect() doesn't redirect to the view, it instead returns plain html of the full page in the console. What could be the cause?
I tried:

```
return view('posts');
return redirect('posts');
return redirect()->route('posts.all');

(with front slashes too)
```

scripts.js:

```
$('.submitBtn').click(e => {
    const title = $('#title').val();
    const tags = $('#tags').val();
    const postText = $('#postText').val();
    const token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    const data = {title, tags, postText};

    const config = {
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/posts/create_post',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token,
      },
      data,
      success: (data) => {
        console.dir(data)
      },
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, thrownError, ) => {
        console.dir(data);
        console.log('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
        console.log('thrownError: ' + thrownError);
        console.log('message: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    }
    $.ajax('/posts/create_post', config);
  });
```

My PostsController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostsController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request){
      $validated = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'postText' => 'required',
      ]);

      if($validated){
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->tags = $request->input('tags');
        $post->postText = $request->input('postText');
        $post->save();
        return redirect('/posts');
      } else {
        return redirect('/add-post')->with('error', 'Something went wrong!');
      }
    }
}
```

My routes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('posts.all');
Route::get('/new', 'PostsController@createPost');
Route::get('/{id}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::post('/create_post', 'PostsController@store')->name('api.create_post');
```

My RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
 /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

            Route::prefix('posts')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api/post.php'));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Post your ajax code

Comment: The redirect works, otherwise you wouldn't get the full HTML of the page you want to visit, but if you are using ajax you can't redirect in PHP, you will need to redirect in JavaScript after the request has been completed.

Comment: @MaulikShah ajax added in edit

Comment: @Remul Oh i see. So if i want to redirect in php i have to use html form with action and method?

Comment: @Avend47 No you can use `window.location.href="url"`. You can pass url from your controller.

Comment: Instead of returning a redirect, you should send something like `response()->json(['redirect_to' => route('api.create_post')], 422)`. This will send an error code back to your jQuery instead of 200, and you can handle redirection in your error handling callback.

Comment: With AJAX it wont' work. There is also not defined `/add-post` vs '/create-post' route.